# try to test my endpoint that sends a mail to a client but it returned mail port exception error at runtime

Tags: email, smtp, port

i was trying to test one of my endpoint(to send a mail to a client) but it throws an error saying that  Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost 25, timeout -1. The port number i used for my smtp configuration is 465.[this is a screenshot of the error from intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI4xY.png)i tried changing the port to 25 and 587 but still returning same error

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask